# RDF integers in R

Tags: r, type-conversion, rdf, sparql

I'm loading data through [rrdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rrdf/index.html) in my R app.
I can handle the URIs no problem, but when it comes to integers I don't know how to convert them into R integers. E.g. `5^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer`

If I try with

```
sub( "^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer", "5^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer" )
```

But I get
`Error in is.character(x) : 'x' is missing.`
Any hint?

Comment: `sub` takes three arguments. You gave it two. So "x" is missing,

Comment: You have not told us what you are tyring to do (perhaps the basic problem with the question in its current state.) Furthermore "^" is a special character in regex, so you should educate yourself at the help(regex) page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with this R function:

```
utils.rdfIntToInt <- function( intStr ){
    intValue <- sub("\\^\\^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer",x=intStr,replacement="")
    return(as.integer(intValue))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of looking foolish:  I know of no  "^^" in R syntax.  What are you trying to do?  Can you provide a sample of your data, and explain why you think it isn't in a format that R recognizes as an integer?